# Are typesetting questions allowed on the main math site?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, typesetting

I would like to know if questions pertaining to "how something should be formatted" (and not how to format it) are allowed on the main math.stackexchange site<sup>1</sup>.

Suppose we don't want to know how to typeset something, but rather, we want to know if it's common practice to typeset it a certain way. Or suppose we would like to know the popular convention for typesetting/expressing a specific mathematical concept.

Questions such as:

- Is it common to format . . .
- What is the proper way to write . . .

For example:

> If I have an equation with a known variable expressed by a letter ($k$ in this case), what is the proper way to format the value of the variable?
>
> May I define the value to right of the equation?
>
> > $$ 200k \, e^{-kt} \qquad , \qquad k=.02586$$
>
> Or must the value be defined in the proceeding/preceding line?
>
> > $$200k \, e^{-kt}$$
> >     where $k=.02586$

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I know that questions related to $\LaTeX$ should be posted on that respsective site. I consider those "how to" questions for actually formatting text once someone already knows how they want it formatted.</sub>

Comment: I think the example falls under _primarily opinion-based_: suppose person A says "do it the first way", and person B says "do it the second way". Then what?

Comment: Although the site isn't meant to operate like this, I suppose the two differing opinions would imply, at least to me, that either way is acceptable. In a very roundabout way, I guess that would answer the question: "May I define the value to right of the equation?". In this case, I think the way the question is worded can heavily influence the answers and their subsequent value.

Comment: Your example questions is a bit unclear. The first is IMO not a good way  to write things yet this has nothing to do with it "being on the same line" I would write, eg: $$200 k e^{-kt} \text{ where } k=.0929$$ on one line. I know the point is not to answer this question here. But the remark is meant ot show some potential pitfalls with such questions.

Answer (score 6):

There are two meanings of *"how to format mathematical text"*:

1. it could mean *"How do I tell LaTeX to do what I want?"* (e.g., what packages exist for X)
2. it could mean *"How should I decide what I want?"* (e.g., what conventions exist for X)

In my opinion, questions about (2) are on-topic here, whereas questions about (1) are for TeX.SE, or possibly for the MathJax maintainers (since MathJax $\neq$ LaTeX)

Comment: This is a nice way to put it. I would however add to 2 that the questions should be about  "mathematical conventions." I think *general* typesetting questions should be off-topic.

Comment: Welcome back to meta, it's been a while.